# Keep lines found in separate list

Tags: join, awk, sed, grep

I have two files

File 1:

```
##HEADER#########################
##HEADER#########################
1       69078   70017   +       .
1       324295  324394  +       .
1       324428  325605  +       .
1       327735  328214  +       .
1       367646  368605  +       .
1       621093  622042  +       .
1       664485  665108  +       .
1       721405  721918  +       .
1       762080  762571  +       .
1       861308  861407  +       .
1       865533  865718  +       .
1       866395  866494  +       .
```

and File 2:

```
1       69078   70017  
1       324295  324394
1       762080  762571
1       861308  861407
1       865533  865718
```

I would like to keep the lines in file 1 that match columns 2 & 3 in file 2. Resulting in this output (including keeping the header in file 1):

```
##HEADER#########################
##HEADER#########################
1       69078   70017   +       .
1       324295  324394  +       .
1       762080  762571  +       .
1       861308  861407  +       .
1       865533  865718  +       .
```

Thanks so much!

I have tried to use this code:

```
join --header -1 2 -2 2 file1 file2 > output
```

But it doesn't recognise the multiple header lines and creates multiple columns not just the ones shown.

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts in form of code in their question, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know, cheers.

Comment: [man join](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html)

Comment: Apologies @RavinderSingh13 and thank you Kamil I have updated with attempt using join. But have also tried: ``` sed -E -i.bak 's/[:blank:]] + $/<files.txt ```

Comment: This is one of those questions where I know the answer, but it's sufficiently easy that I really feel that the person asking it should figure it out for themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```
 awk '{key = $2 OFS $3} NR == FNR{seen[key]; next} FNR <= 2 || key in seen' file2 file1
```

```
##HEADER#########################
##HEADER#########################
1       69078   70017   +       .
1       324295  324394  +       .
1       762080  762571  +       .
1       861308  861407  +       .
1       865533  865718  +       .
```